# ImageIcon shows wrong image on retina display

Tags: java, image, macos, swing, retina

I am loading an image from an URL like this:

```
new ImageIcon(new URL(url))
```

The url is something along the lines of http://example.com/image.png, so an image on the internet.

This works just fine, however I've been getting a few reports of users of my program that they are getting strange images instead of the regular ones when using the program on a retina display on Java 8u20 (and maybe later).

I determined that the strange images they are getting is an image that the CDN the images are loaded from automatically redirects to if the image wasn't found. After some research, I found that newer versions of Java apparently automatically add @2x into the url when using the `Toolkit.getImage(URL url)` method (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8011059), which is used by `new ImageIcon(URL url)`.

The problem of course is that the CDN actually returns a valid image if the image isn't found, so Java probably thinks it actually found a higher resolution image to use on the retina display. Other images in my program that also use `ImageIcon` in the same way, but are loaded from another source, seem to work just fine.

The question is now, what would be the best way to resolve this? I don't have access to the CDN, so I have to prevent Java from trying to load the second URL somehow (if that is actually the problem, but it certainly seems that way). Unfortunately I don't have a computer to test this on, so it's a bit hard to tell which solution will work.

Comment: ..what's the CDN?  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).